# C# Regular-expression check a string of hex value with semicolon-seperate

Tags: c#, regex, hex

I want to write a regular-expression to check whether a string expression fit the rule which only contains hex value with semicolon-seperated?

```
A valid string looks like: "0x01;0x02;0X03"

An invalid string may be: "0z01;0x02,003"
```

So how should I write this regular-expression? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this pattern: 0x\d{1,2};

Comment: @Sunil Won't match `0X03`

Comment: @Sunil: what about A-F ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
  string source = "0x01;0x02;0X03";
  string pattern = @"^(0[xX][0-9A-Fa-f]+)(;0[xX][0-9A-Fa-f]+)*$";

  bool matched = Regex.IsMatch(source, pattern);
```

If you want hex values represent, say `byte`, i.e. be in `[0x00..0xFF]` range

```
  string pattern = @"^(0[xX][0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2})(;0[xX][0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2})*$";
```

Answer (score 1):

This rexex is what you need.

```
0(x|X)(\d|[a-fA-F]){1,};
```

Comment: Why matching `;`?

Comment: Be careful with `\d` in .net: `\d` mtach *any* digit, say persian one: `۳` `۴`, put `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option to exclude them

Comment: If u need to find the number with the `;` character, this regex is true. Else you sholud remove `;`, so `0(x|X)(\d|[a-fA-F]){1,}`. For exclude persion digits you must use `0(x|X)([0-9]|[a-fA-F]){1,}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
(0[xX][A-Fa-f0-9]+;?)+$
```

Comment: Why matching `;`? No need for +$.

Answer (score 0):

I would use combination of string split and regex

```
string input = "0x01;0x02;0X03";

Boolean valid = input
 .Split(new char[] { ';' })
 .All(x => Regex.Match(x, "0[xX[0-9a-fA-F]{2}").Success);
```